# Horizontal bundle visualization?

Tags: fiber-bundles, connections

I would like some intuition for the horizontal bundle, could someone please make a drawing for me? I found a nice pucture here https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ehresmann_connection.png#mw-jump-to-license so I kind of understand the vertical bundle (it seems to be the paths in the total space which are mapped to a point in the base space), but I got stuck at understanding what the horizontal bundle is (some kind of complement is all I got). I did not understand what the red squares in the image represented in terms of paths. Does horizontal bundles need to have paths that are in a plane in the total space somehow ? How are they mapped into the base space (and fiber)?

Comment: Verticality is provided by the bundle itself, however, for horizontal stuff one usually needs a *covariant differential* (or *connexion*) to be given on the bundle.

Comment: I have gotten lost among all the definitions. Something that takes scalar fields to scalars and something that takes fibers to fibers at different base points seem to be needed in most, I think a good picture would help me more at this point.

Comment: (Or perhaps I looked at the wrong definition, it was a bit unclear why a cotangent space mapping scalar fields to scalars popped up, I expected fibers or maybe tangent vectors)